# gwt gss lighten() and darken()

Tags: gwt, sass, gss

i was trying to use lighten() and darken() in GSS (i'm gwt 2.8 version and material-design rc4) like so:

```
@def MAIN_COLOR #64b5f6;
@def LIGHTER_COLOR lighter(MAIN_COLOR, 0.5);

.lighter {
color: LIGHTER_COLOR;
}
```

but the result is

```
.lighter {
color: lighter(#64b5f6,0.5)
}
```

i cannot find any sample of using those functions anywhere..
https://github.com/google/closure-stylesheets

i was expecting that those work like in SASS

```
$primary-color: #64b5f6;
$darken: darken($primary-color, 7%);
$lighten: lighten($primary-color, 20%);
```

thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that like SASS, the function is `lighten()`, not `lighter()`.

Comment: i tried both "lighten" and "lighter" - none of them is evaluated

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your exact behaviour, but I have managed to get a working example and found the following:

- The function name is `lighten`
- The lighten function takes an integer number between 0 and 100 as the amount to lighten by. This is documented [directly in the code](https://github.com/google/closure-stylesheets/blob/master/src/com/google/common/css/compiler/gssfunctions/GssFunctions.java#L728) on GitHub.

I've tried modifying your example as follows and it is working fine:

```
@def MAIN_COLOR #64b5f6;
@def LIGHTER_COLOR lighten(MAIN_COLOR, 5);

.lighter {
color: LIGHTER_COLOR;
}
```

This is evaluated, using the latest version of Closure Stylesheets (right now,
 [v1.4.0](https://github.com/google/closure-stylesheets/releases/tag/v1.4.0)) to become the following:

```
.lighter{color:#7cc1f7}
```

I expect the number is a percentage lightness increase - that's the method I use in [my own color software](https://markembling.info/2010/12/colour-chooser) and is generally what other CSS preprocessor lightening/darkening functions use too - so you might need to play around to get the exact shade you're looking for.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: thank you for comment, unfortunately it is not rendered in my case..
it looks like this anyway
https://pasteboard.co/aarbivgpU.png

Comment: it seems that GssFunctions in gwt does not contain lighten and darken functions yet.. :/

Comment: Is all the GSS stuff turned on? I've just looked through the release notes for GWT releases and it looks like it might not be enabled by default. See [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_0_BETA1) and [here for migration details](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/gss_migration.html) - including enabling the GSS config property.